# Exporting wordpress posts with gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, export

so I want to export WordPress posts to pdf or doc and I accomplished that using plugins like Aspose pdf/doc exporter, but I faced the problem previous it specialist uploaded images into gallery and because of that, those plugins can't find any pictures inside post and because of this my post gets exported just as simple text. Of course I can do it manually but that would take tons of my time so is there any way to accomplish this?